# How are old encrypted messages recovered for the sender?

Tags: public-key

Take ProtonMail as an example. It encrypts all emails with some kind of asymmetric keys. But obviously, they can't store my private so the key must be obtained when I log in. This means, they must be able to generate the same key multiple times. I thought they used my password to deterministically generate the keys, but then I changed my password and I was still able to open my old emails. How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you can do it: use a key derived from the password to encrypt your long-term private key.

- When you want to register an account with password $\mathit{pw}_0$:

  1. Generate a key pair $(\mathit{sk}, \mathit{pk})$.
  2. Generate a salt $s_0$.
  3. Derive $k_0 = \operatorname{Argon2id}(\mathit{pw}_0, s_0)$.
  4. Compute the ciphertext $c_0 = \operatorname{AES-GCM}_{k_0}(\mathit{sk})$.  (Set nonce = 0.)
  5. Store $(\mathit{pk}, s_0, c_0)$.
- When you want to read your mail:

  1. Rederive $k_0 = \operatorname{Argon2id}(\mathit{pw}_0, s_0)$.
  2. Decrypt $\mathit{sk} = \operatorname{AES-GCM}_{k_0}^{-1}(c_0)$ (or report authentication failure).
  3. Use $\mathit{sk}$ to decrypt mail.
- When you want to change your password to $\mathit{pw}_1$:

  1. Rederive $k_0 = \operatorname{Argon2id}(\mathit{pw}_0, s_0)$.
  2. Decrypt $\mathit{sk} = \operatorname{AES-GCM}_{k_0}^{-1}(c_0)$.
  3. Generate a fresh salt $s_1$.
  4. Derive $k_1 = \operatorname{Argon2id}(\mathit{pw}_1, s_1)$.
  5. Compute the ciphertext $c_1 = \operatorname{AES-GCM}_{k_1}(\mathit{sk})$.
  6. Replace $(\mathit{pk}, s_0, c_0)$ by $(\mathit{pk}, s_1, c_1)$ and erase all copies of $c_0$.

(This is presumably close to what ProtonMail does.)